# JButton is not adding

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton

I'm not sure why my JButton is not displaying when I add it to the JPanel class: if my class extends JPanel, shouldn't this.add be sufficient? And if I remove this Jpanel class from another Jpanel, the components attached to this panel should disappear as well right? Thank you!

```
public class Menu extends JPanel{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

static boolean startGame = false;

public static String user;

public Menu(final JFrame frame) {
    JPanel userName = new JPanel(); // create new JPanel
    final JTextField text = new JTextField();
    text.setText("input your username here");

    //adds userName input box to the panel

    Action action = new AbstractAction(){

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        user = text.getText();
        text.setVisible(false);
        Menu.startGame = true;
    }};

    text.addActionListener(action);

    userName.add(text);
    frame.add(userName, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.revalidate();
    frame.repaint();

    setFocusable(true);

    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            sndMenu newMenu = new sndMenu(frame);
            newMenu.setVisible(true);
        }
    });

/** 
  * this does not display help!
 */

    //add a button to the menu called "help"
    JButton help = new JButton("get instructions");
    this.add(help,BorderLayout.CENTER); 
    help.setVisible(true);

    help.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            instructions instr = new instructions(frame);
            frame.add(instr);
            frame.revalidate();
            frame.repaint();
        }
    });
}

public void paint (Graphics g) {    
    super.paint(g);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, Game.WIDTH, Game.HEIGHT);  

    Font fnt0 = new Font("Manaspace", Font.BOLD, 40);
    Font fnt1 = new Font("Manaspace", Font.BOLD, 30);
    g.setFont(fnt0);
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.drawString("Welcome To Jumping Box!", 120, 300);
    g.setFont(fnt1);
    g.drawString("Click to play!", 260, 400);
}

}
```

Comment: Your `Menu` `JPanel` is never added to anything. Try `frame.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);` for instance .

Comment: Don't use a MouseListener on a button. You should be using an ActionListener to perform an Action when the button is clicked.

Comment: @Berger actually, my menu jpanel is added to the frame. The menu shows up, but the button does not appear.

Comment: @MischiefManaged the posted code is not showing the **Menu** being added to the frame - are you sure? Only the `userName` panel is being added (according posted code)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger yep so I have another class called Main.java that adds the JPanel to the frame, which is initiated in Main.java. I want to add the JButton to the JPanel because I'm hoping that the JButtons only appear when I add the JPanel, not when Jframe is set to visible

Comment: Never mind. So it appears that my button exists - it's just invisible, but when I click on where the button is supposed to be, my action is still executed

Comment: You have two frames, which one is actually meant to be visible? Also, don't use `MouseListener` with a button, use an `ActionListener`, which will take into account the user using the keyboard